# How to run a kedro pipeline interactively like a function

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, kedro, data-pipeline

I would like to run kedro pipelines in jupyter notebook with different inputs, so something like this:

```
data = catalog.load('my_dataset')
params = catalog.load('params:my_params')
pipelines['my_pipeline'](data=my_dataset, params=my_params)
```

Is there a way to do this? Also, if I have to feed some inputs to other nodes but the starting one (for example the second node), how would this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We actually have a native way to use Kedro in notebook environments, [check out the docs here](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tools_integration/ipython.html).

Answer (score 3):

Concerning running the pipeline in jupyter, you can use one of the available runners or a custom one. The SequentialRunner is an example and can be used as follow:

```py
from kedro.runner import SequentialRunner

SequentialRunner().run(pipeline = your_pipeline, catalog = your_catalog)
```

if you are using the kedro jupyter lab or notebook, the catalog is available, otherwise you can create it using DataCatalog().
You can add datasets to your DataCatalog using the add_feed_dict method or the add and save methods (set the flag replace to True if you want to overwrite the dataset in the catalog)

```py
import pandas as pd
from kedro.io.data_catalog import DataCatalog

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [0, 1], 'col_2': [1, 2]})
io = DataCatalog()

io.add_feed_dict({"new_dataset": df }, replace=True)
```

If you want to start a pipeline from a specific node after having changed some entries in the catalog you can use the from_inputs method that Pipeline objects have.

Answer (score 1):

So, to specify @datajoely's answer: In IPython / Jupyter Notebook just run

```py
session.run(pipeline_name='my_pipeline', from_inputs=['my_dataset', 'params:my_params'])
```

No need to load data / params specifically using `catalog.load()`.
I don't think there is a way to feed alternative inputs to intermediate (non-entry) nodes of the pipeline. For that, I would just call each node separately.